# How do I access an android library from my apk

Tags: android, android-studio

I've created an android library that lacks any UI.  I made it as an android library instead of a regular java library in Android Studio because it needs access to a context.  What this means it that if an android application needs to use this library, it must pass in it's context.  I could just do this in my android app, but if I separate it out the code will be reusable.

I had this library as a standalone android project.  How do I access this library from my android app?  If I import it into my app as a module gradle complains:

Warning:Dependency MyAndroidApp:MyLibrary:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: /MyLibrary/build/outputs/apk/mylibrary-release-unsigned.apk

Comment: "If I import it into my app as a module gradle complains" -- it seems as though the library is actually an application. You want `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` in the module's `build.gradle`, not `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`.

Comment: thanks, that worked!